# Pickle Error 13 Permission Denied when accessing directory made by os

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I am trying to read from a file made by the os but it returns a permission error

```
os.mkdir('currentdir/test')
pickle.dump(face_encoding,open('currrntdir/test/t.pkl','w+b'))

Encodingun = pickle.load(open('currentdir/test','r+b'))
```

And I get the error on the third line

P.S I'm using Windows 10

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing some brackets

Comment: Sorry...I just fixed it

Comment: you are missing the filename in your load statement

Answer (score 0):

Is `currrntdir` in this line a typo or an error in your code? Isn't it `currentdir`?

```
pickle.dump(face_encoding,open('currrntdir/test/t.pkl','w+b'))
```

Your implementation for saving and loading pickle files should be like the following

```
from os import makedirs
from os.path import exists

path = 'currentdir/test'
pickle_fn = path + '/' + 't.pkl'

if not exist(path):
    makedirs(path)

with open(pickle_fn, "wb") as file_path:
    pickle.dump(face_encoding, file_path)

with open(pickle_fn, "rb") as file_path:
    encoding = pickle.load(file_path)
```